# Strange behaviour of remote objects feature on different orgs

Tags: remote-objects

I run the same js call to retrieve cases and on 1st org it works and on the 2nd org it results in error like:

```
Error occurred while performing RETRIEVE operation on sobject: Case with data: {limit=5, offset=5, where={IsClosed={eq=false}}} (MALFORMED_QUERY: 
createddate, casenumber, priority, _cid FROM Case WHERE IsClosed =
                                  ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:88
line 1:88 no viable alternative at character '_')
```

On the 2nd org RO feature automatically  append unknown field _cid to query and claims about this.

Beside this I cannot register any new dev edition as it reports that my any username(random) already exists. Some strange things happens...

Comment: my initial code is the same as Keith suggested. But the problem that the code written according to the spec works on some org and doesn't work on another...

Comment: Are the orgs the same type?

Comment: different dev environments